# Google Maps adjusting to include users and address

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, gis

I am trying to make some adjustments to code and the developer is no longer available to assist. i am clueless when it comes to the GMaps api and code but still I am trying to figure out.

Problem is we have users on the map and we wanted the map to auto zoom in to include all of the users. This we were able to do. However we have a main address that should be included in that to... so what we want to do is auto zoom close enough to include the farthest point, whether it is a user OR the main address. To demonstrate, look at the URL below:

http://app2.wehaveeyes.com/reports/maps/maps2.cfm

If you zoom out you'll see the main address is about 5 miles away. [image: Here is what it shows now...]

But this is what we would like it to auto zoom to include the main address[image: Map with all users and address]

Below is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="10">

    <style>
        /* Set the size of the div element that contains the map */
        #map {
            height: 100%;  /* The height is the height of the web page */
            width: 100%;  /* The width is the width of the web page */
        }

        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .user_info {
            background-color: ##0000;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #fff;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY">      
  </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.sobekrepository.org/includes/gmaps-markerwithlabel/1.9.1/gmaps-   
 markerwithlabel-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Initialize and add the map
        function initMap() {
            var xml_data = "<MAP>" + 
                    "<location>1 South Main Street, Akron Ohio</location>" + 
                    "<user_info>" + 
                    "<user_name>Scott jones</user_name>" + 
                    "<user_lat>41.141756</user_lat>" + 
                    "<user_lon>-81.675599</user_lon>" + 
                    "<user_img>https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.wbur.org/wordpress/1/files/2015/03/AP736858445562.jpg</user_img>" +
                    "</user_info>" + 
                    "<user_info>" + 
                    "<user_name>Bill James</user_name>" + 
                    "<user_lat>41.142758</user_lat>" + 
                    "<user_lon>-81.657274</user_lon>" + 
                    "<user_img>https://s.abcnews.com/images/US/jeff-koenig-ht-ml-190122_hpEmbed_2_4x5_992.jpg</user_img>" + 
                    "</user_info>" + 
                    "<user_info>" + 
                    "<user_name>Karrie Sims</user_name>" + 
                    "<user_lat>41.135809</user_lat>" + 
                    "<user_lon>-81.639336</user_lon>" + 
                    "<user_img>https://www.odmp.org/media/image/officer/23891/orig/police-officer-natalie-corona.jpg</user_img>" + 
                    "</user_info>" + 
                    "<user_info>" + 
                    "<user_name>John Smith</user_name>" + 
                    "<user_lat>41.142855</user_lat>" + 
                    "<user_lon>-81.637319</user_lon>" + 
                    "<user_img>https://www.odmp.org/media/image/officer/24262/400/deputy-sheriff-jake-allmendinger.jpg</user_img>" + 
                    "</user_info>" + 
                    "<user_info>" + 
                    "<user_name>Jim Deek</user_name>" + 
                    "<user_lat>41.131543</user_lat>" + 
                    "<user_lon>-81.653541</user_lon>" + 
                    "<user_img>https://lawofficer.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/blakesnyder.jpg</user_img>" + 
                    "</user_info>" + 
                    "</MAP>";

            var parser = new DOMParser();
            var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml_data, "text/xml");
            var address = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("location")[0].textContent;
            var users = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("user_info");
            var user_list = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                user_list.push({
                    "name": users[i].getElementsByTagName("user_name")[0].textContent,
                    "lat": users[i].getElementsByTagName("user_lat")[0].textContent,
                    "lng": users[i].getElementsByTagName("user_lon")[0].textContent,
                    "img": users[i].getElementsByTagName("user_img")[0].textContent
                });
            }

            // The location of US
            var map_center = {lat: 39.8283, lng: -98.5795};
            // The map, centered at US
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 3, center: map_center});

            // boundary of all pins
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

            // converts address into geolocation with lat and lng
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            codeAddress(geocoder, map, address);

            // adds user_info marker
            for (const index in user_list) {
                lat = parseFloat(user_list[index]["lat"]);
                lng = parseFloat(user_list[index]["lng"]);

                var point = {lat: lat, lng: lng}
                var lbl_content = "<div style='text-align: center;'><div><img src='" + 
                        user_list[index]["img"] + 
                        "' width='30px' height='38px' style='border: 2px solid #000; display: block; margin: 0 auto;'></div>" + 
                        "<div style='background-color: #000; padding: 2px;'>" + 
                        user_list[index]["name"] + 
                        "</div></div>";
                var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                    position: point,
                    icon: {
                        url: "./res/police_pin.png",
                        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(40, 40)
                    },
                    map: map,
                    title: user_list[index]["name"],
                    labelContent: lbl_content,
                    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                    labelClass: "user_info",
                    labelInBackground: true
                });

                // extends boundary
                bounds.extend(point);

                // shows coordinate tooltip with 4-decisions
               // var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                //    content: lat.toFixed(4) + ", " + lng.toFixed(4)
               // });
               // infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }

            // fits map
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }

        /////////////////////////////////////////
        /// converts address into geolocation ///
        /////////////////////////////////////////
        function codeAddress(geocoder, map, address) {
            geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function (results, status) {
                if (status === 'OK') {
                    // relocates the map centered at address pin
    //                        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,
                        icon: {url: "./res/911_call.png", scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(55, 55)}
                    });

                    // shows coordinate tooltip with 4-decisions
                    //lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    //lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                    //var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    //    content: lat.toFixed(4) + ", " + lng.toFixed(4)
                    //});
                    //infowindow.open(map, marker);
                } else {
                    alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                }
            });
        }

        ////////////////////////////
        /// reads local xml file ///
        ////////////////////////////
        function readTextFile(file)
        {
            var allText = "";
            var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
            rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
            rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
            {
                if (rawFile.readyState === 4)
                {
                    if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
                    {
                        allText = rawFile.responseText;
                    }
                }
            }
            rawFile.send(null);
            return allText;
        }

        initMap();
    </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

I have gone through so many boards and have tried working with the code but nothing has worked. Any help would be great.

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Make your function `codeAddress` return the geocoded location of the address, and do the same `bounds.extend(foo)` with that address that you are doing for the other points.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try. So are you saying in a sense combine address with user marks?

Comment: Sort of - the point is that you're currently doing `bounds.extend(point)` for all points that are users; but you aren't using the 911 point to extend the bounds. You could combine them, or you could just run that function over the 911 point independently.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will certainly give it a try!!! Appreciate you help!

Comment: Thanks again alphabetasoup! From a coding standpoint, would you have a suggestion on how to edit the code to do this? I am horrible when it comes to the Google API code and end up breaking more than I fix. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that every significant location is covered within the map viewport, you could use the `map.fitBounds()` method. As per this [doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.fitBounds), this method

> Sets the viewport to contain the given bounds.

I see that you are already implementing this method to display every users. That said, you just have to add the (what you call the) `main address` on the bounds.

To add the main address' coordinates to the bounds instance, you just have to use the `bounds.extend()` method.

I checked the code on the [site](http://app2.wehaveeyes.com/reports/maps/maps2.cfm) and here's what you can do to achieve this:

1. Make the variable `bounds` a global variable by moving it above your `initMap()` function.
2. On your `codeAddress()` function, add the `main address`' coordinates by extending the `bounds`. Here's a code snippet for that:

   ```
   // Add the main address' coordinates by using bounds.extend method
   // results[0].geometry.location contains the main address' coordinates
   bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
   ```
3. Move the `map.fitBounds()` method just below the `bounds.extend()` method on Step #2.

   ```
   // fits map
   map.fitBounds(bounds);
   ```

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wq62eb1c/) that's based on your code.